# Why do some programs not start when I launch them in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows

I just installed Windows 7 and I'm finding that some older (3 years) programs don't even launch when I double click on them.  I opened up Process Explorer and the process don't even flash in the list when I double click on them; it's like the programs aren't even trying to start.

What could be the reason for this?

Comment: What programs? What version and architecture of Win 7? Is the account you're using an administrator? Do you have UAC on?

Comment: Did you upgrade from windows 7? Did you do a clean install?

Comment: http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Comment: Swing some REAL examples, I've been running Win 7 for a long time, maybe I can help you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For programs that are truly incompatible with Windows 7, and if you have 7 Ultimate or 7 Business, you could use [XP Mode](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/download.aspx).

Really, though, I agree with the commenters: edit your question to be clearer.

Answer (score 0):

You could try right clicking and going to compatibility options and running it under the old OS.

Answer (score 0):

You can try right click on the program (setup/run file) compatibility tab and choose the last version of vista. (check the first option and choose the last vista version)